# pêches pluriel pour les poissons ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, pluriel

J'ai vu le mot "pêches" (pluriel) pour les poissons, pas les fruits sur Wiktionnaire, en français et en anglais les deux. Il dit que le mot est invariable mais a aussi les formes singulier et pluriel le deux.

C'est bon ou pas ? Comment utiliser "pêches" (pluriel) dans une phrase ?

---

I saw the word "pêches" (plural) for fish (fishing), not the fruit (peach) on Wiktionary, both in French and in English. It says that the word is invariable but also has both singular and plural forms.

Is this right or not? How do you use "pêches" (plural) in a sentence?

---

- Wiktionnaire en français : [pêche](https://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%AAche)
- Wiktionary in English: [pêche](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%AAche#French)

Answer (score 2):

Well "pêche" (fishing) and "pêche" (peach) have both a plural form :

> Ces pêches sont très juteuses.
>
> Il existe plusieurs types de pêches en bateau.

But the color "pêche" has no plural form because it is an adjective derived from a name.

Like Greg said :

Color adjectives that are derived from a noun (pêche, orange, marron, etc) are invariable (with some exceptions such as "rose"). Ex: `des chemises pêche`.

Comment: About the adjective for the color: this is consistent with a general rule: color adjectives that are derived from a noun (*pêche, orange, marron,* etc) are invariable (with some exceptions such as *rose*). Ex: *des chemises pêche*

Comment: So it's only with "types of fishing", like "types of milk"? e.g. "There are two milks to choose from: cow's milk and goat's milk."

Comment: No you can use it without talking of types. If you look on the French wikipedia (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%AAche_(halieutique))  for example you can see some examples: `améliorer le rendement des pêches`, `les pêches françaises`,...

Comment: My French is not good enough to grasp that subtlety. Can you explain those phrases in English?

Comment: Well now that I think about what you said before, I think there is a very small subtlety  between `les pêches françaises` and `la pêche françaises` . I guess the latter is about the field and the first suggest we talk about all the types of fishing.